# I have this script, it's used on WP. The problem is that the image is blinking and I don't know how to solve this issue. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have this script, it's used on WP. The problem is that the image is blinking and I don't know how to solve this issue. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var yOff = 15;
    var xOff = -20;
    var pathToImage = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png";

    $(".text-hover-image").hover(function (e) {
        $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    },

    function () {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text").remove();
    });

    $(".text-hover-image").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");
    });
});
```

```css
span {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is my paragraph with a <a class="text-hover-image" href="#">very special hover</a> effect on the link.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>The hovering works with every element that has <span class="text-hover-image"> a class of <em>"text-hover-image"</em></span>
```

Comment: if you change the source of the image the pic keep blinking this my issue

Comment: You keep removing and adding the image - but I'm not clear what you want to happen. One of the (other) problems is that you are sensing mouse movement on the one bit of text, most of which is obscured by the image. What action should move the image - should it be any mouse move on the page? And when should the image disappear.

Comment: Try to change this link or example, when I run it on WordPress and when I mouseover the text the image keeps blinking
https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/249-2499432_support-technical-information-icon-drop-shadow-crm-call.png